# SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE, что-то пошло не так

Tags: sql, select, insert, xls

Есть файл import.xls, в нем данные формата:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | num    |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 0A3478 |
| 2    | 0A3479 |
| 3    | 0A3480 |
| 4    | 0B1267 |
| 5    | 0C3498 |
+------+--------+
```

Делаю импорт в sql посредством:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Data Source=C:\Folder\import.xlsx;
   Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml')...[sheet$]
```

Есть таблица куда в дальнейшем нужно вставить эти значения:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLES(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    NUM int NOT NULL
)
```

В ней есть данные, допустим это:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | num    |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 0A3478 |
| 2    | 0A3479 |
| 80   | 9X0298 |
| 90   | 9X6941 |
| 100  | 0W5963 |
+------+--------+
```

И если сделать импорт xls сначала в таблицу, например #tmp, и сделать запрос вида:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tmp
WHERE num not in (SELECT num FROM TABLES)
```

То запрос ничего не возвращает, а должен по идее:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | num    |
+------+--------+
| 3    | 0A3480 |
| 4    | 0B1267 |
| 5    | 0C3498 |
+------+--------+
```

Делал сотни раз выгрузки из xls, и тут до банального все просто, но что-то не идет, и глаз так скажем "замылился", нужен свежий взгляд, подскажите кто тут не так))

Comment: А вы содержимое #tmp проверяли ? может там num равен NULL.

Comment: Да, там ровно все строки которые были в файле..

Comment: Тогда это какая то загадка. В голову только приходит, что в таблице TABLES колонка называется не num и подзапрос в not in под num понимает эту колонку из #tmp. попробуйте явно указать `TABLES.num` что бы исключить такое недопонимание.

Comment: Да, это какая-то непонятная жесть) Причем, самое интересное, что если сделать не NOT IN, а наоборот IN, то возвращаются 2 первые строки, с id 1 и 2..жесть

Comment: А если вместо num использовать id (для теста, понятно что в данных они могут не совпадать)

Comment: весь и прикол залить  только те номера которых нет

Comment: Это я понимаю. мне просто интересно как поведет себя ваш глючный not in на более простых, числовых данных

Comment: Проверьте, нет ли в таблице TABLES записи, где num=NULL. Если да, то добавьте в запрос SELECT * 
FROM #tmp
WHERE num not in (SELECT num FROM TABLES WHERE num IS NOT NULL)

Comment: странно, но да...ээх